# telegram doesn't show the image preview link always with my amazon afiliates

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram channel and since yesterday it does not show **the image preview of the links** that I send with a **bot**.

I send links with my ID of **amazon afiliates** and it doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

```
bot = telegram.Bot(bot_token)
bot.send_message(bot_chatID, 
    text='<b>Hello</b> \n <a href="//www.amazon.es/dp/B076MMCQWW?psc=1">https://www.amazon.es/dp/B076MMCQWW?psc=1</a>', 
    parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)
```

[Telegram message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABMXl.png)

Comment: Please provide more details, a snip code. Your question is general.

Comment: And please remove the tags `python` and `python-telegram-bot` (unless your code involves those) ;)

Comment: sorry, you can see the code now. But it is not the problem. I think if you send in telegram a link many times maybe telegram "banned" you...

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create a link preview and not using `html` markup, then this  might help you:

```py
bot = telegram.Bot(bot_token)
bot.send_message(
    bot_chatID, 
    text='''*Hello*
[https://www.amazon.es/dp/B076MMCQWW?psc=1](https://www.amazon.es/dp/B076MMCQWW?psc=1)
''', 
    parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.MARKDOWN,
    disable_web_page_preview = False
)
```